Option to have two month on air-datepicker library with pure HTML, CSS, JS
I'm trying to setup the air-datepicker for two month view on desktop and one month view on mobile but it's not succeeded, any recommendation how to achieve that?

       // Initialize the Datepicker only once
    if (!pickerInitialized) {
        picker = new AirDatepicker('#datepicker-input', {
            inline: true,  // Display inline
            range: true,   // Enable range selection
            multipleDatesSeparator: ' - ', // Separator for date range
            showOtherMonths: true,  // Show adjacent month days
            numberOfMonths: 2,  // Show two months at the same time
            locale: englishLocale, // Set to English locale explicitly
            minDate: new Date(), // Disable past dates,
            onSelect({date, formattedDate}) {
                // Get the start and end date of the range
                selectedStartDate = date[0];
                selectedEndDate = date[1];


The author of this library has been working on this very recently. The code is currently in a separate branch called multiple-calendars. It appears that you invoke it by specifying calendars: 2 when instantiating the Airdatepicker. Not sure if it’s responsive and will automatically adjust back to 1 calendar on mobile devices.

You right, I tried to add this attribute on the setting but it's not works, that's why I posted the question :)
Do you know how to setup it?

@Guyb there are a bunch of example of usage shown on the official docs here https://air-datepicker.com/examples . The functionality to select a range of dates is given by range:true and you already did it (you will find it under Range of dates). While the chance to select the beginDate and endDate from two individual data-pickers (instead of an actual range on a single calendar) is under Minimum and maximum dates. By the way in my very humble opinion I find it very annoying. I think is much better to select a range on a single datepicker if you asked me.. but that's not the question

@DiegoD Thank you for the detailed resonse! I did try to use it with the "Minimum and maximum dates" but as you said it will not work on the two month together as one. like it will not marked the selected date-range with this option.
I'm not sure this libary support it at this time :/

that's the point! the range can be selected only in a single calendar (as far as I could see watching all the available examples).. when using such arrangement, the first date clicked selects the beginDate and the second click selects the endDate... thus creating a range that will be used to fill the correspondent <input type="text"> with dd.mm.yyyy - dd.mm.yyyy. While if you use the double picker arrangement, you are selecting two individual dates that will be used to fill two distinct input with two distinct dates that in your logic you will use to make a range.

your question hides some arbitrary choices that you need to better focus. Showing the range spanning different months inside 2 different calendars will create some confusion in terms of usability in my opinion and I have no idea if it's supported in automatic by the library itself. Do you have a reference you are inspiring to? Did you see that exact scenario used in some web site like for flights for example?

@DiegoD Exactly like flights datepicker that you select start-end date range. This is my scenrio I'm looking for and tried to implement it with vast datepicker libraries

here on github issue describing an attempt at showing multiple calendars based on configuration. Things said there are pretty confusing and don't seem aligned with the current release. As far as I can say, to do what you are aiming to, you need to have 2 pickers and than handle their events so that you can deal with showing a custom range overriding the automatic behaviour and at the same time also override the whole logic filling the input field with the selected range.

Or instead of using such library you may use another one already supporting such feature .. try searching for "Date Range Picker" that will be strictly focused on that

one last thing.. the author suggests to add the tag air-datepicker when asking on SO. I try editing your question doing so but it looks like such tag doesn't exist at all and it seems worthless creating it for the sake of one question because it sounds like the author itself didn't care to set it up by himself (so why should he be listening here?)

@DiegoD Yes this is why I have open the discussion here, very confusing.
Thank you for the desire to help

since it's unclear how to have it using air-datepicker without implementing it using a very custom logic, I would suggest you another library called flatpickr. I have an example achieving the exact scenario you asked for but using flatpickr. I didn't post the answer yet because you still didn't clarify if it's ok for you to change that requirement

@DiegoD Yes thank you, I will open him bug on Github, I don't think it will be with this is. I have checked: flowbite datepicker, Flatpickr, pickaday, litepicker, daterangepicker as well. each one of them have different advantages and disadvantages.  It will be great to see the example you saying you have, Thank you for youe help!

I undeleted the answer since you said you are curious to see a working demo with another library.. and it happens to be flatpickr (one of those you cited in that list).

Since it's unclear how to achieve that result by using air-datepicker without implementing a custom solution I may suggest a similar approach by using a different library https://flatpickr.js.org/
This one supports the chance to show an arbitrary amount of consecutive months by setting the showMonths prop in the object used for initializing the date picker. Such option might be decided based on the available width using an arbitrary breakpoint (I used 768 in this example).
To make sure the picker will be adapted to the current viewport, the picker must be initialized every time the window is resized (thus I added the handling of the resizeevent).
This looks like the way to get that result with the minimum effort.
The configuration speaks for itself for the other options like firstDayOfWeek, rangeSeparator, dateFormat.
You may also style the picker using css if you need further customization.


function initializeDatePicker() {
  
  //this decides how many consecutive months (1 or 2) based on available width
  const numberOfMonths = window.innerWidth <= 768 ? 1 : 2;

  flatpickr("#datepicker-input", {
    mode: "range",
    inline: true,
    showMonths: numberOfMonths,
    minDate: "today",
    dateFormat: "d.m.Y",    
    locale: {
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,
      rangeSeparator: " - ",
    }
  });
}

initializeDatePicker();

//re-initialize the date picker on window resize (so to adapt the correct 1/2 months according to width)
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  document.querySelector("#datepicker-input")._flatpickr.destroy();
  initializeDatePicker();
});
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Select Date Range</h1>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker-input" placeholder="Select date range">
</body>



